# Regular expression for characters inside square brackets

Tags: regex, powershell, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on creating a regular expression in PowerShell.  This is the start of a postbuild event from VS2012 to transform sql so that my table names and column names don't have any spaces in them.  Once this works, I can modify a script I already have to replace the content of a file with a regex string.  I've been working with [this tutorial](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_regex.htm#PowerShell_Regex_Replace_Text), but I can't seem to replace the space (\s) with an underscore when that space is between an open and closed square bracket.

Here's an example of how I'd like to transform the sql:

Convert:

```
select * from [Existing product] where [Existing product].[Desc value] = 26
```

To:

```
select * from [Existing_product] where [Existing_product].[Desc_value] = 26
```

When I run this script in powershell ISE:

```
#Example of PowerShell Regex Replace
$newline = '
'
$strText = 'select * from [Existing product] where [Existing product].[Desc value] = 26'
$Pattern = '(?<=\[)(\s(?<=\s))(?=\])'
$New = "_"
$newline
'SourceText: '
$strText
$newline
$strReplace = [regex]::replace($strText, $pattern, "$New")
"We will now replace $Pattern with $New :" 
$newline
$strReplace
```

I get this result:

```
PS C:\> C:\REGEX.ps1

SourceText: 
select * from [Existing product] where [Existing product].[Description value] = 26


We will now replace (?<=\[)(\s(?<=\s))(?=\]) with _ :


select * from [Existing product] where [Existing product].[Description value] = 26
```

Where I hope to see the string with spaces replaced with underscores, above.

My regex is currently `(?<=\[)(\s(?<=\s))(?=\])` but apparently it only selects spaces where the square bracket is right next to it.  What am I missing from the regex above?

Please let me know if you have any questions and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless you add in padding it will only select exact matches.

Maybe `(?<=\[.*?)(\s(?<=\s))(?=.*?\])` already does the trick for you. But in general, your regexp seems A) overly complicated, and B) regexps aren't the right tool for this job IMHO.

I don't think the regexp will work in general. How about a string like this:

```
[a] [b]
```

I believe this will be turned into

```
[a]_[b]
```

Maybe `(?<=\[[^\]]*?)(\s(?<=\s))(?=[^\[]*?\])` works, maybe it doesn't - it is a mess either way!

You really should consider to just extract all `\[([^\]]*)\]` groups, then with a second step rewrite these.

SQL probably is *not a regular language*, but context free. (See Chomsky Hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks for your post! Yes, your second option, `(?<=\[[^\]]*?)(\s(?<=\s))(?=[^\[]*?\])` did the trick for what I was looking for.  Thanks again!

Comment: I also tested it with multiple spaces between the square brackets and it worked for that too!!

Comment: It's still a hack. I don't think regexp is the "swiss army chainsaw" that we should use to chop everything.

Comment: It's faster than iterating through each char in the file and doing string replacement.

Comment: It's probably not faster than using a more appropriate parser. It may pay off to use e.g. http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/ to get properly parsed queries, then output them in their rewritten form.
But it's your choice. If the regexp work for your unit tests, it's okay by test driven development principles.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
$string = 'select * from [Existing product] where [Existing product].[Desc value] = 26'

$string -replace '(\[\S+)\s(\S+\])','$1_$2'
```

select * from [Existing_product] where [Existing_product].[Desc_value] = 26

It gets more complicated if there's more than one embedded space.

```
 $string = 'select * from [Existing product one] where [Existing product one].[Desc value] = 26'

[regex]$regex = '(\[[^\]]*\])'

$regex.Matches($string) | 
%{$string = $string -replace [regex]::escape($_.value),($_.value.replace(' ','_'))}
$string
```

select * from [Existing_product_one] where [Existing_product_one].[Desc_value] = 26

Comment: I was able to get this to work too! I'm going to use the other solution though because I can drop in the new regex.  Thanks for the post though!